# What is the most efficient way to get the last line break in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have the following function to get the last line break position in a string:

```
function getLastLineBreak (content) {
    function reverse(s){
        return s.split("").reverse().join("")
    }
    var reversed = reverse(content)
    var index = content.length-reversed.indexOf("\n")
    return index
}

var myString = "some text \n next linet \n another link \n 123"
indexIs = getLastLineBreak(myString)
console.log("index is", indexIs)
console.log("text after", indexIs, myString.substr(indexIs,myString.length))
```

Is there a way using regular expression to pick up the last line break position within the string in nodejs?

Comment: why not use `(.*$)`?https://regex101.com/r/tN1dW4/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
var myString = "some text \n next linet \n another link \n 123";

document.write(myString.lastIndexOf('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
(.*$)
```

We can take advantage of the fact that `.` do not matches new line.

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Pkx8OY)**

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /(.*$)/g; 
var str = 'some text \n next linet \n another link \n 123';
matches = re.exec(str);
document.writeln(matches[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the old fashioned way. `/(\r?\n)[^\r\n]*$/`

This should start from the end of the string and work backwards.
Where the last linebreak is probably closest in most cases.